# Integrating $\sin^4 x$ using Taylor series

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, indefinite-integrals

We can solve this problem by simplifying using trigonometric identities but, I was trying to find different methods to solve trigonometric integration problems, and Taylor series is something which I am trying to use to solve some.

$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}…$$

So we have $$\int (\sin x)^4= \int (x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}…)^4$$

But I don’t know how to proceed.

Also is it advisable to use this method for such problems, or am I overcomplicating it?

Answer (score 2):

It is less complicated if you use double angle formula $$ \sin^2x = \frac {1}{2}(1-\cos 2x )$$ and  $$ \cos^2x = \frac {1}{2}(1+\cos 2x )$$

to expand $\sin ^4 x $ and then integrate the result.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

When you can directly find using substitutions or some other method
you need not use the Taylor series,

Observe that $$ \int \sin^4 x\, dx = \int \sin^2x \,dx - \int \sin^2x \cos^2 x \, dx =\int \sin^2x \,dx - \frac14\int \sin^2{2x}  \, dx $$

and you can easily evaluate $\int \sin^2 t \, dt$ by writing $\sin^2t $ in terms of $\cos{2t}$.

**Update:**

Let $$ S = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k$$ we refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series), $$S^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{k}a_ja_{k-j}x^k$$

I think directly considering $\sin^4(x)$ would be laborious to compute coefficients as we have to square twice, instead that I suggest you to write and calculate square using the above equation
$$ \sin^2 x = \frac{1 - \cos{2x}}{2} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{ 2^{2k-1}x^{2k} (-1)^k}{(2k)!} $$

This may help you in guessing a simple form for the coefficients after the integration thereby getting a simple form for the antiderivative.

Comment: Yes but I want to learn how to solve using the Taylor series, just to know a few more approaches to the same question

Comment: I will add that in answer but generally finding a simpler form for the coefficients in the product of two power series is not very easy in general.

Comment: Thanks! I will keep that in mind.